# How to fix the error "Cannot load control TabStrip" in VB6 program?

Tags: vb6, microsoft-common-controls

When I am trying to build the exe in VB6, I am getting a pop up saying that a particular form cannot be loaded. When I checked its log file, it says "Cannot load TabStrip."

The same thing is working fine in another machine having Microsoft Visual Basic 6
(SP5) and running Windows server 2003. But we are facing issue when we are trying to build this in Windows Server 2012.

Can anyone please help me out with this ?

Comment: you are missing an activex dll (or not registerd)

Comment: should be part of the "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0".

Comment: Yes mscomctl.ocx is already registered, I even re- registered it again but it still the same issue.

Comment: Maybe this SO question is a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727568/visual-studio-6-windows-common-controls-6-0-sp6-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Tried this also but still not working.

Comment: No more ideas from my side

Comment: The VB6 IDE is [not supported on Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikosan/archive/2012/04/20/support-statement-for-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-8.aspx). Rather than fight this for a development tool that was end-of-lifed 7 years ago, create a Windows XP VM and do your VB6 development there.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366109/how-do-i-fix-the-error-cannot-load-control-sspanel-license-not-found-in-vb6-p