# Can't open project in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I was given a test program by one of my friends well compiled and the challenge was to edit the source code. I got to know the program was written in VB6 and I got the vb-decompiler. I got lots of forms (.frm files) and a project.vbp . Now, I downloaded the VB6 for Windows from unofficial sources and when I import my project, I get out of memory error on every form. I ignore the error and when import is complete, It give a message about a log file -

```
Line 77: Cannot load control txtServer.
Line 85: Cannot load control txtUID.
Line 93: Cannot load control txtPwd.
Line 101: Cannot load control txtFTPPath.
Line 109: Cannot load control txtFTPSharedFolder.
Line 117: Cannot load control txtPort.
Line 222: Cannot load control txtType.
Line 266: Cannot load control txtPath.
Line 274: Cannot load control txtSharedFolder.
Line 310: Cannot load control cmdSave.
```

I tried to update my vb6 to vb.net through visual basic 2008 express but I get errors

```
upgrade failed: application has caused an exception
```

What should I do now?
Edit :
I read the frm file. I opened the frm file and saw it had lines like -

```
begin xyz.txtServer
```

Now xyz is the name of application and txtServer is the error in the log file as stated in the question.

Edit 2:
I have a new development. I opened the frm file and got to know that the line having - begin VB.(some Command) runs perfectly but the line - begin xyz2000(some command) gives error. It is clear that it is dll error. The frm does not call any xyz2000.dll . I did not get any xyz2000.dll in the software given to me. So where did this xyz2000 came from?

Comment: VB.NET is not a true successor to VB6, it is an entirely different language & programming environment which has a lot of superficial similarities. So that probably won't be a good quick fix to the problem you have.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268991/how-to-fix-the-error-cannot-load-control-tabstrip-in-vb6-program

Comment: I think you should probably find something more productive to do with your life. This friendly challenge is gonna waste a lot of hours

Comment: @DaveInCaz The VB.NET language itself is close to being a superset of VB; the huge differences are in the libraries, especially between the WinForms of VB.NET and the Ruby forms library of VB.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Ruby?

Comment: Ruby was the code name of Visual Basic's programmable forms engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "cannot load" errors are most likely due to DLL (or OCX files, a type of DLL) references which are missing or at least not registered on your development computer. VB6 is not a statically linked language, or even truly dynamically linked, but instead DLL references are all discovered at runtime based on COM - essentially meaning that DLLs generally have to be centrally registered in Windows.

To further diagnose the specific issues:

- Look in the FRM files in a text editor. File where the control "txtServer" is defined and what type it is. The type name may indicate which DLL is required to provide the control.
- Look the top of the FRM files, you should see lines listing `Object = "..."` references. These also indicate required DLL / OCX files.
- Look in the .VBP file, you will see similar `Object` and `Reference` lines.

(If you add some examples of those items to the question people may be able to provide more help.)

Comment: I had nearly ten .dll files in the program sent by my friend. I just tried to register them centrally, but only half were registered. Others gave error such as not a valid entry point was found or version error not compatible in both 32bit and 64bit regsvr32. I suppose the really main ones were registered.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta it can be the case that some DLLs are not COM dependencies and therefore don't require registration. i.e., a COM DLL can have a non-COM DLL as a dependency. Also VB6 can directly use such DLLs (but not for controls). So you may be OK based on those errors.  VB6 is 32-bit so it is always the 32-bit regsvr32 you should be using, AFAIK. And you must make sure to run regsvr32 as admin (which it seems like you probably did).

Comment: Should I send you source code for compiling. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta this does nto seem to be a coding problem, but a development environment problem. You need to work through each error one-by-one.

Comment: I have a new development. I opened the frm file and got to know that the line having - begin VB.(some Command) runs perfectly but the line - begin xyz2000(some command) gives error. It is clear that it is dll error. The frm does not call any xyz2000.dll . I did not get any xyz2000.dll in the software given to me. So where did this xyz2000 came from?

Comment: @BhavyaGupta could you have a missing DLL?

Comment: I have all the dll that I got from the software. There were two exe files when  the software Installed. Both run the same thing. One was smaller than other. Should I decompile the other?

Comment: @BhavyaGupta that is confusing... I would do so just to see what you might learn.

Comment: Thanks DavelnCaz, what should I do now to get the log. I have got another development. The program created a shortcut which runs in /appdata/roaming/microsoft/installer/(GUID)/(something).exe.    The exe is not running itself alone. I could not find that guid in regedit too.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely carefully examine the `.vbp` file. The `Reference` and `Object` statements GUID's must appear in the registry's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib` key.

Those are the components you register with `regsvr32`. For the `dll's` you couldn't register, they have to be copied to a location accessible by 32-bit applications. The best location is:

**On 64-bit Windows**

`%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`

**On 32-bit Windows**

`%SystemRoot%\System32`